# spring mvc bean scope singleton seem not work properly

Tags: spring-mvc

Please help me
I am new spring mvc user. In controller i call a singleton bean like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView student(@RequestParam(required = false) String name) {
    ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml" });
    Student student = (Student) context.getBean("student");
    if (name != null && name.length() > 1) {
        student.setName(name);
    }
    System.out.println("name:" + student.getName());
    return new ModelAndView("result", "student", student);
}
```

The first time, i enter url in browser: http://localhost:8080/example/student?name=myname
The system print result like that: name:myname=> it's ok

The second time, i enter url in browser: http://localhost:8080/example/student
The system print result like that: name:null

Why? you said that a single bean instance be created for every request? 
So the first time the name of student was set is "myname". The second time, when i request again, if a single bean instance was created, the name of student must be "myname", because it was set in first time request?But in my case, the second time request, seem that a new bean instance be created? So the name value is null

Thanks very much

Comment: if i remove "ApplicationContext context = 
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml"});" and use "@Autowired private Student student"  then a single bean instance be created for every request. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Spring is doing what you have exactly asked for.

```
ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml" });
```

Everytime you are making a request, you are creating a new instance of parent context. And hence you are not getting the bean with a singleton scope.

When you use ,

> @Autowired private Student student

you are not creating context for every request. Hence your bean is getting created with a singleton scope.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton instance means through out the applications only single instance of bean will be created by the spring containers like BeanFactory or ApplicationContext.

When ever you supplied your *.xml configuration file to BeanFactory or ApplicationContext containers then they will read specified bean declarations and starts instantiate them as singleton by default.

In your case you are specifying your *.xml to containers for each request to "/student" so, for every request of "/student" instances will be created.

study this link to configure your xml files to spring container for web applications
  http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html